# python parse html with entities

Tags: python, html, parsing

```
string = """<div property="gr:description" content="&lt;P&gt;&lt;TABLE border=0 cellSpacing=0 

cellPadding=0 width=605&gt;&lt;COLGROUP&gt;&lt;COL width=605&gt;&lt;/COL&gt;&lt;/COLGROUP&gt;&lt;TBODY&gt;&lt;TR height=121&gt;&lt;TD class=xl66 height=121 width=605&gt;• Open Dimensions:&nbsp; 29.25”H x 71.71”W x 29.38”D&lt;BR&gt;• Black blow mold top&lt;BR&gt;• Durable, easy-to-clean top surface&lt;BR&gt;• Table has centerfold and convenient handle for easy transport and storage.&nbsp; &lt;BR&gt;• Compact flat fold&lt;BR&gt;• Strong steel frame.&lt;BR&gt;• Multi purpose – can be used for dining, work, crafts, etc.&lt;BR&gt;• Great for parties, weddings and holidays – indoors &amp; out.&lt;/TD&gt;&lt;/TR&gt;&lt;/TBODY&gt;&lt;/TABLE&gt;&lt;/P&gt;" xml:lang="en"></div>"""
```

What is the best way to decode this? It shows up normal in stack overflow output

Comment: Fixed your question - please use descriptive titles and proper formatting for your source.

Comment: you should describe your problem more clearly so that masses can understand your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
from htmlentitydefs import name2codepoint
import re
def unescape(s):
    "unescape HTML code refs;"
    return re.sub('&(%s);' % '|'.join(name2codepoint),
               lambda m: unichr(name2codepoint[m.group(1)]), s)

>>> unescape(string)
u'<div property="gr:description" content="<P><TABLE border=0 cellSpacing=0 \ncellPadding=0 width=605><COLGROUP><COL width=605></COL></COLGROUP><TBODY><TR height=121><TD class=xl66 height=121 width=605>\u2022 Open Dimensions:\xa0 29.25\u201dH x 71.71\u201dW x 29.38\u201dD<BR>\u2022 Black blow mold top<BR>\u2022 Durable, easy-to-clean top surface<BR>\u2022 Table has centerfold and convenient handle for easy transport and storage.\xa0 <BR>\u2022 Compact flat fold<BR>\u2022 Strong steel frame.<BR>\u2022 Multi purpose \u2013 can be used for dining, work, crafts, etc.<BR>\u2022 Great for parties, weddings and holidays \u2013 indoors & out.</TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></P>" xml:lang="en"></div>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the [html5lib](http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/) to parse HTML strings.

```js
from html5lib import treebuilders, treewalkers
_html = "<your html string>"
parser = html5lib.HTMLParser(tree=treebuilders.getTreeBuilder("dom"))
walker = treewalkers.getTreeWalker("dom")
dom = parser.parse(_html)
stream = walker(dom)
for element in stream:
    print element # just a debug output
```

Comment: Title says "parse html", description says "decode string to proper html". What do you want now?